# Can't open xib in project navigator

Tags: ios, xcode, xib

I'm having a problem and need your assistance.
I've just updated my project using svn and got a conflict; now I get this warning:

```
The document ....xib could not be opened.  
This archive contains a reference to an object with the identifier "150009670"  
but does not contain an object with a matching identifier.
```

After this I opened `.pbxproj` with text editor and changed the reference to the object `150009670`. Now the project builds and works as expected but when I try to open my xib from the project navigator I still get the warning.
I'm using svn for the first time so what's wrong? why did I get a conflict in the first place? can I fix this without rebuilding the xib?

Comment: Can you open the xib from the Finder?

Comment: Are you getting same warning again or it's different than previous?

Comment: Do you get some error, if you open this file from the Finder and not from your Project? What kind of error do you get if you close all projects in Xcode and open this file from the Finder?

Comment: @iMx I've already tried opening it from finder and get the same warning

Comment: If you are deploying in Simulator, see if you can build the app, if you remove all folders from <Username>/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/

Comment: If not, if fear you have to checkout this file from svn and make your last changes one more time

Comment: Problem solved:D  deleted the whole project and after that used svn checkout

Answer (score 0):

If you are using svc there might be a head attached somewhere in the file if you performed any merges and there are conflicts.

View your project file with a text editor where you will be able to see the generated XML code. (Use something like text wrangler, sublime text 2). Search for the term "HEAD". This will hopefully find instances with the following format:

```
<<<< HEAD
         code1
=======
        code2
>>>>>>>>>>>
```

Remove these stuff and the code that you dont want, then save the file. Code1 will refer to newer code, code2 will refer to older code. Look at it and decide what you need to keep. If you aren't sure either keep both or remove code1.

Answer (score 0):

xCode seems to hold some of the changes with svn added in the project. Right click on the xib file and select discard changes. This should reset the erroneous information tied to the file and allow you to run the project.